# триггер в mysql вызывает ошибку при создании

Tags: mysql, триггер

собственно прошу подсказать, как создать триггер. Есть таблица, при обновлении данных в ней, хочу в одном поле переписывать данные. Таблицы и поля ест-но существуют

```
CREATE TRIGGER `catalog_trig1` BEFORE UPDATE
ON `catalog_all`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET `datatime` = DATE();
```

При выполнении ошибка - синтаксическая. Может кто подсказать, что неправильно написал?

UPD

```
SQL execution error #1064 Response from the database

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-db_product.catalog_all FRO EACH ROW BEGIN SET catalog_all at line 1
```

Comment: "ошибка - синтаксическая" - текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос, плиз

Comment: Уберите слово `BEGIN`. А вообще - надо цитировать текст ошибки, а не констатировать факт её наличия.

Comment: извиняюсь. добавил

Comment: А почему в сообщении об ошибке `FRO EACH ROW `, обратите внимание на первое слово. нам то вы текст нормально написали, FOR ...

Comment: ошибка из редактора MySQLFront - перепечатал

Comment: Да и само место ошибки не совпадает, никакого `-db_product` у вас в запросе нет. Попробуйте с консоли, если ваш клиент самовольно меняет запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю подойдет:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `catalog_trig1`
BEFORE UPDATE
ON `catalog_all`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `catalog_all`
  SET `datatime` = DATE(CURDATE());
END;
```